# How do I build/compile Aubio for Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, ndk-build, waf, aubio

Aubio is a tool, written in C, that analyzes sound files. It is compatible for android, ios and many more platforms.

My Question: Is there a step by step guide on how to build aubio for android - or at least a list of all the tools needed (waf, ndk, CMake, etc.) and how and when to use them? I have only developed apps for android in java before.

I just want to run a simple given example from the project.

I have already read the developer guides for android ndk and tried to figure out what to do with the waf files and the android example script. But i could not figure it out. (the ndk seems to use CMake, but i dont know how to use that correctly on my files and if it would work out)

The installing guide on the official website from aubio in the section for android is not very helpful and it feels outdated as the ndk seems to be integrated within the sdk since some time.
(not helpful: https://aubio.org/manual/latest/installing.html#android)

Do you have any ideas where I could at least start to search for?

Comment: The script `script/build_android` does cross compile of the library and the programs on android, provided it is modified to point to the path to the NDK.

Comment: If you (rightly) find that the documentation is lacking, please open a bug report and we will help you there.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I will report the bug. I know that script, but I couldn’t get it to work out yet. I have no experience with the ndk and all that comes with it. So until the documentation isn’t fixed, I will leave the ticket open. Probably somebody can give me a hint where to inform myself to make the current example script working.